# Duda en HTML CSS Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un ejercicio que me pide una página web con 2 pestañas utilizando Bootstrap además de HTML. Tengo este código HTML (lo pongo desde la etiqueta body porque no me deja poner más):

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Atención</h1>
            <p class="lead">Esta página es solo una prueba de Bootstrap</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
        </div>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#pestaña-uno">Pestaña 1</a>
            </li>  

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pestaña-dos">Pestaña 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>  

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane container active" id="pestaña-uno">         
                <h1>Este es el contenido de la pestaña 1</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="pestaña-dos">
                    <h1>Este es el contenido de la pestaña 2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>   

    </div>         





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js integrity="sha384UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
```

La cuestión es que no me muestra nada al pinchar en "Pestaña 2", como que no navega de una pestaña a otra, y me muestra el contenido de las 2 pestañas en la "Pestaña 1".
¿Alguien sabe por qué y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Observo dos cositas.
1. No uses Ñ para referenciar clases o id.
2. no incluiste el CDN de Bootsrap  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

checa el script

```
   <body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Atención</h1>
        <p class="lead">Esta página es solo una prueba de Bootstrap</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#pestaa-uno">Pestaña 1</a>
        </li>  

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pestaa-dos">Pestaña 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>  

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane container active" id="pestaa-uno">         
            <h1>Este es el contenido de la pestaña 1</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="pestaa-dos">
                <h1>Este es el contenido de la pestaña 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>   

</div>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js integrity="sha384UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Puede ser que la parte del código donde se visualiza el CDN lo haya omitido

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta. El uso de la letra Ñ en las clases o IDs no implica error de ejecución. El OP **sí** está incluyendo las CDNs de Bootstrap en su código. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 5):

Tienes varios errores

- el primero es que estas asignando los dos tabs como `active`, debes quitar uno para que se puedan mostrar correctamente.
- lo segundo, es que estabas envolviendo los `tab-pane` en `tab-container`, cuando en realidad solo necesitas uno el cual envuelve todos los tab-pane
- tercero, ten cuidado con el `script`, tienes uno que no esta con las comillas

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#pestaña1">Pestaña 1</a>
        </li>  

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#pestaña2">Pestaña 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>  

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="pestaña1">         
            <h1>Este es el contenido de la pestaña 1</h1>
        </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="pestaña2">
                <h1>Este es el contenido de la pestaña 2</h1>
            </div>          
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Nos cuentas como te va :)

Comment: lo acabo de probar y nada, acabo de subir el código con esos cambios

Comment: @AitorOrtega Tienes razon, no solo era eso.. la acabo de editar!